# Add image column to Sharepoint Foundation list

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, list-definition

Trying to use Visual Studio to add an image/thumbnail column to the schema.xml of a  Sharepoint Foundation list (Can't use the Type="Image" as this is Foundation).  Any ideas?

TIA

Answer (score 4):

In SharePoint Foundation, there is only one option when you need some OOTB column for displaying picture: use 'Hyperlink or Picture' column. This column is represented by [SPFieldUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldurl.aspx) class, which have DisplayFormat property, which can be either `Hyperlink` (default) or `Image`.

In CAML (i.e. in schema.xml), you will need provide following attributes to [Field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms437580.aspx) element:

1. Type="URL"
2. Format="Image"

Comment: I did this..created a list item and added a url to the picture which is in the content database but it was displayed.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In your `Schema.xml` add this or change your column like below code:

```
<Field Name="Picture" ID="{6eeec5fa-ed6f-495d-9622-e5362e6925aa}" DisplayName="Picture" Type="URL" Height="150" Width="224"  Format="Image" />
```

In eventreceiver or User Control or in Feature:

To get value from a URL Field:

```
SPFieldUrlValue urlField = new SPFieldUrlValue(item["Picture"].ToString());
string description = urlField.Description;
string url = urlField.Url;
```

To assign to a URL Field:

```
SPFieldUrlValue urlField = new SPFieldUrlValue();
urlField.Url = "http://www.xyz.com";
urlField.Description = "xyz";
item["Picture"] = urlField;
```

.